# Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on ‘MSYSObjects’

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

In VB.NET, I want to check whether the table "LEDGER_FULL" exists or not.

I'm using this query:

```sql
SELECT MSysObjects.Name, MSysObjects.Type 
FROM MSysObjects 
WHERE (MSysObjects.Name='LEDGER_FULL') AND (MSysObjects.Type=1)
```

My database is an MS-Access database. Once it execute the above query, I get this exception:

> Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on ‘MSYSObjects’

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use MS Access system objects. In most cases, you'll have permission issues. You can access the database information (e.g., tables, views, etc.)  using `OleDbConnection.GetSchema`.

Here's the function I use to check if a table exists or not:

```
Public Shared Function TableExists(tableName As String) As Boolean
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim dt As DataTable = conn.GetSchema("Tables")
        Dim tables As String() = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of String)("TABLE_NAME")).ToArray
        Return tables.Contains(tableName)
    End Using
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
If Not TableExists("LEDGER_FULL") Then
    ' The table doesn't exist. Do something about it.
End If
```

Hope that helps.